# Participe passé ou infinitif

Tags: infinitif, participe-passé

While reading "Astérix aux Jeux Olympiques" by Goscinny and Uderzo, I found the following expression (uttered by Agecanonix):

"Ça, c'est parlé comme un ancêtre !"

Is this grammatical? I would have written "parler" instead of "parlé", unless the verb is used as a transitive verb, which looks rather odd to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, ta surprise est légitime dans la mesure où *Parler* est un verbe le plus souvent employé intransitivement.

SAUF... sauf quand il est question de langue où, là, il est utilisé transitivement.
Il est même transitif direct :

*Parler sa langue maternelle. Parler la langue française, parler le français. ils parlent patois, argot. On disait aussi Parler gascon, normand pour Parler avec l’accent gascon, normand.*

Dans l'expression que tu cites, il n'y a donc absolument aucune faute à utiliser le participe passé.

Comment: Bien sûr, je comprends que le verbe "parler" peut être utilisé transitivement, mais ici "Ça" se rapporte à une phrase dite juste avant, pas à une langue. Je me demande d'ailleurs si la version avec l'infinitif est fausse, le sens étant "Ça, c'est [ce que j'appelle] parler comme un ancêtre"

Comment: @Maiaux : Le participe passé est ici adjectivé. Comme on dirait très correctement : * Bien dit ! * ou encore * ça c'est bien dit * dans  *ça c'est parlé* parlé est utilisé adjectivement, attribut de c'.

Comment: D'ailleurs on pourrait remplacer la phrase d'exemple par "Ça, c'est dit comme un ancêtre." ou encore "Ça, c'est énoncé comme un ancêtre". A chaque fois on sous-entend "...comme un ancêtre l'aurait fait".

Comment: Est-ce que la version avec l'infinitif (qui donc aurait un sens et une emphase peut-être légèrement différents) est acceptable?

Comment: @Maiaux : Oui, elle serait aussi parfaitement correcte. Le sens serait un peu différent dans la mesure où l'usage d'un infinitif entraîne toujours une nuance de vague, de généralisation, de règle. Beaucoup moins ici et maintenant, *sur ce coup-là* que le suggère le participe passé adjectivé. Dans ton exemple, le mot d'Agecanonix est vraiment motivé par la situation. Agecanonix s'en voudrait certainement de donner à Abraracourcix une approbation enthousiaste valant pour **toutes** les fois dans **toutes** les circonstances où Abraracourcix, (ou un autre) dirait la même chose.

Comment: En bref *ça c'est **parler** comme un ancêtre* impliquerait presque qu'à chaque fois que quiconque, en n'importe quelle circonstance, dit ce qu'Abraracourcix a dit, il parle comme un ancêtre.